# Magento 2 - How to override LESS code from _extends.less?

Tags: magento2, less, magento2.3.4

I try to remove the **box-shadow** of a button in the customer area.

[image]

I found the code in

**vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source\_extends.less**:

```
//
//  Secondary button
//  ---------------------------------------------

& when (@media-common = true) {
    .abs-revert-to-action-secondary {
        &:extend(.abs-revert-secondary-color all);
        .lib-css(border-radius, @button__border-radius);

        &:not(:focus) {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow);
        }

        &:active {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow-active);
        }
    }
}
```

I added my override to a new file

**THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\_overrides.less**

```
//
//  Secondary button
//  ---------------------------------------------

& when (@media-common = true) {
    .abs-revert-to-action-secondary {
        &:extend(.abs-revert-secondary-color all);
        .lib-css(border-radius, @button__border-radius);

        &:not(:focus) {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, false);
        }

        &:active {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I used **false** in `lib-css()` because in the Magento UI Library Documentation (lib/web/css/docs/utilities.html) it says:

> The **.lib-css()** mixin is used to set any css property if there is a
>   value passed to it by a variable. Also .lib-css() can add -ms-,
>   -webkit- and -moz- prefixes if needed.
>
> If the variable is set to **false**, the .lib-css() **mixin will add nothing
>   to the code**.

Then I imported the file into

**THEME\web\css\source\_extend.less**

```
@import 'lib/extend/_overrides';
```

But the original code is still getting loaded from the following file and my override does not get applied:

**/pub/static/frontend/hausfux/base/de_DE/css/source/_extends.less**

Where do I have to add my override to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code. Hopefully, it will resolve your problem.

**THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\_overrides.less**

```
@button__shadow: false;
```

**Alternative (not recommended):**

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .abs-revert-to-action-secondary {
        &:extend(.abs-revert-secondary-color all);
        .lib-css(border-radius, @button__border-radius);
        &:not(:focus) {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, none);
        }
        &:active {
            .lib-css(box-shadow, none);
        }
    }
}
```